# Change Global Scrollbar Color with XAML

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I'm trying to change the color of each part of the scrollbar for ScrollViewer, ListView, and RichTextBox using XAML.

This works as a global override for all Scrollbar Backgrounds.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF191919"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF191919"/>
</Style>
```

But I need a style color for each part.

- ScrollBar
- Thumb
- RepeatButton

Using `Style TargetType` doesn't work for any other part.

The Thumb and RepeatButtons stay default white/gray.

[image: scrollbar]

Comment: If you're willing to edit the `ScrollBar` template, it's definitely doable.